# Preview changes made to AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avmutablecomposition

I use `AVMutableComposition` to perform a **scaleTimeRange**  operation on an `AVAsset`.
 Everytime time  the *timeRange* is scaled (i.e. slow motion is done on the video), I have to export it using `AVExportSession`.

Q) I was wondering if there is a **lighter way to preview** the **asset** whenever I perform `scaleTimeRange` , instead of having to export the Asset everytime to view changes.

I read that `AVPlayerItem` is helpful, but I can't understand how.

Comment: Have you tried with the rate property of AVPlayer? If you set a rate value between 0.0 and 1.0 you actually see the video in slowFoward. check this link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate

Comment: Unfortunately , that doesn't help because the video cannot be **saved** in a fastforward/ slow-mo state using the `rate` property . Apparently I will have to nail both the `rate property` and the `scaleTimeRange` at once to make it work. 
I am not quite sure though how that would happen either.

Comment: That's what a meant. You can "preview" the video varying the rate property, pick a value for staleTimeRange and then saved with the AVMutableComposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `AVPlayerItem` from an `AVAsset` using `AVPlayerItem(asset:)`. Also, an `AVMutableComposition` is an `AVComposition` is an `AVAsset`.

See the overview in the documentation for `AVMutableComposition`. There is an example of doing exactly that: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmutablecomposition

```
let composition: AVMutableComposition = ...
let snapshot = composition.copy()
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: snapshot)
```

Comment: Thanks again Dave y)